# Extracting arabic text from pdf

Tags: c#, itext

i'm trying to extract this arabic text from pdf file using iTextSharp

> تُكسِّرُ بَابَ السَّماءِ الوَحِيدَ، وكُلَّ الكَلاَمِ الذي لَمْ نَقُلْهُ، وتَرْحَلْ

```
    private static string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();


        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, strategy);
            //currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(UTF8Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            text.Append(currentText);
        }

        return text.ToString();
    }
```

but it gives me this random result

> ُ ُ ّ سِ ك
> ُ ت ُ َ ب ا
> َ ب ُ ء ا م
> َّ س ل ا ُ ،
> َ د ي
> ح
> َ و ل ا ُ َّ ل
> ُ ك و ُ م
> َ لا َ ك ل ا ي ذ ل ا ُ م
> َ ل ،
> ُ ه
> ْ ل
> ُ ق
> َ ن ُ ل
> َ ح
> ر
> َ ت و

Comment: You have to use correct font.

Comment: It looks sort of ok. Except I think you display the result Mirrored to an arab speaking user. (I don't speak arab)

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik the font name is calibri how to extract it based on that font name ?

Comment: install ARIALUNI.TTF, and try to use this font.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle in this example some letters were put in a random order because the letters are vowelized

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is solved here - [extract arabic from pdf to string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602268/extract-arabic-from-pdf-to-string-c-sharp)

In essence you need to use the Windows-1256 encoding to get the letters back the way you need to get them so that they aren't single characters vs what you're getting.

You may need to do some more work when you extract the data from the PDF but the code-snippet in the answer will tell you the two encodings you need to use to get the final result.

P.S. Didn't notice it at first but it's the exact same code you're using, and I have no idea if you've already seen the answer there, but it does solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Melory i modfied my function but this time i'm getting question marks as a result here's what i've changed :
`currentText = Arabic1256ToUtf8(currentText);`